# Getting hostapd and dnsmasq working together

Tags: dnsmasq, hostapd

I have both `hostapd` and `dnsmasq` running but for some reason any connected host does not get assigned an IP. `tcpdump` shows the client pinging the broadcast IP but no response.

**hostapd config**

```
interface=wlx00c0caa5587f
ssid=pepper
channel=6
hw_mode=g

wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=password123
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
```

**dnsmasq config**

```
interface=wlx00c0caa5587f
#except-interface=lo
#except-interface=wlp2s0
bind-interfaces
no-resolv

dhcp-range=192.168.33.2,192.168.33.20,12h

dhcp-option=3,192.168.33.1 # Gateway (gw)
dhcp-option=6,192.168.33.1 # DNS

log-queries
log-dhcp
listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

**Interface commands**

Setting interface IP

```
sudo ifconfig wlx00c0caa5587f 192.168.33.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

Adding route to gateway. I am not sure why this one is needed.

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.33.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.33.1
```

**tcpdump**

```
listening on wlx00c0caa5587f, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:07:23.540357 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from dc:a9:04:d0:c4:76 (oui Unknown), length 300
15:07:23.540386 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from dc:a9:04:d0:c4:76 (oui Unknown), length 300
15:07:24.639657 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from dc:a9:04:d0:c4:76 (oui Unknown), length 300
15:07:24.639735 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from dc:a9:04:d0:c4:76 (oui Unknown), length 300
15:07:27.579717 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from dc:a9:04:d0:c4:76 (oui Unknown), length 300
```

**Main questions**

How do clients search for the DHCP server?

Do I need to set the DHCP server in the hostapd config?

Answer (score 2):

It was my firewall!!!

Big thanks to this  board:
https://community.ui.com/questions/SOLVED-Dnsmasq-No-DHCP-offer/b065563b-a736-4c2f-81c2-e11a1ec70317

The fire wall commands for `ufw` are here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1146048